# Swap Case on javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a script that changes the case, but result from using it on text is exactly the same text, without a single change. Can someone explain this?

```
var swapCase = function(letters){
    for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){
            letters[i] = letters[i].toUpperCase();
        }else {
            letters[i] = letters[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
   console.log(letters);
}

var text = 'So, today we have REALLY good day';

swapCase(text);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't modify them in-place. You'll have to create a new string and return that.

Comment: @DavidThomas `is exactly the same text, without a single change`

Comment: Strings are immutable in JS.

Comment: if instead of a string you pass an array of characters the function actually works:  `swapCase (text.split(''))`. Then at the end of the function you better do a `return letters.join ('')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Ian said, you need to build a new string.

```
var swapCase = function(letters){
    var newLetters = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){
            newLetters += letters[i].toUpperCase();
        }else {
            newLetters += letters[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    console.log(newLetters);
    return newLetters;
}

var text = 'So, today we have REALLY good day';

var swappedText = swapCase(text); // "sO, TODAY WE HAVE really GOOD DAY"
```

Comment: Thank u guys for information, i did not know about it :)

Comment: Kinda wish there was way to do this without the conditional. Too bad JS doesn't come with a transliterate function.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this simple solution.

```js
var text = 'So, today we have REALLY good day';

var ans = text.split('').map(function(c){
  return c === c.toUpperCase()
  ? c.toLowerCase()
  : c.toUpperCase()
}).join('')

console.log(ans)
```

Using ES6

```js
var text = 'So, today we have REALLY good day';

var ans = text.split('')
.map((c) =>
 c === c.toUpperCase() 
 ? c.toLowerCase()
 : c.toUpperCase()
).join('')

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Use `[...text]` instead of `split()`.

Answer (score 4):

guys! Get a little simplier code:

```
string.replace(/\w{1}/g, function(val){
    return val === val.toLowerCase() ? val.toUpperCase() : val.toLowerCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that uses bitwise XOR operator `^`.
I feel this is more elegant than using `toUppserCase`/ `toLowerCase` methods

```
"So, today we have REALLY good day"
.split("")
.map((x) => /[A-z]/.test(x) ? String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0)  ^ 32) : x)
.join("")
```

**Explanation**
So we first split array and then use `map` function to perform mutations on each char, we then join the array back together.
Inside the map function a RegEx tests if the value is an alphabet character: `/[A-z]/.test(x)` if it is then we use XOR operator `^` to shift bits. This is what inverts the casing of character.  `charCodeAt` convert char to UTF-16 code. XOR (`^`) operator flips the char. `String.fromCharCode` converts code back to char.
If RegEx gives false (not an ABC char) then the ternary operator will return character as is.

**References:**

- [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
- [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
- [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)
- [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [Map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: this only works for A-z

Answer (score 1):

One liner for short mode code wars:

```js
let str = "hELLO wORLD"
str.split("").map(l=>l==l.toLowerCase()?l.toUpperCase():l.toLowerCase()).join("")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const swapCase = (myString) => {
  let newString = ''; // Create new empty string
  if (myString.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) { // ensure the parameter actually has letters, using match() method and passing regular expression.
    for (let x of myString) {
      x == x.toLowerCase() ? x = x.toUpperCase() : x = x.toLowerCase();
      newString += x; // add on each conversion to the new string
    }
  } else {
    return 'String is empty, or there are no letters to swap.' // In case parameter contains no letters
  }
  return newString; // output new string
}

// Test the function.
console.log(swapCase('Work Today Was Fun')); // Output: wORK tODAY wAS fUN

console.log(swapCase('87837874---ABCxyz')); // Output: 87837874---abcXYZ

console.log(swapCase('')); // Output: String is empty, or there are no letters to swap.

console.log(swapCase('12345')); // Output: String is empty, or there are no letters to swap.

// This one will fail. But, you can wrap it with if(typeof myString != 'number') to prevent match() method from running and prevent errors.
// console.log(swapCase(12345));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses regular expressions.  It matches each word-char globally, and then performs a function on that matched group.

```
function swapCase(letters) {
  return letters.replace( /\w/g, function(c) {
    if (c === c.toLowerCase()) {
      return c.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return c.toLowerCase();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#this is a program to convert uppercase to lowercase and vise versa and returns the string.

```
function main(input) {
    var i=0;
    var string ='';
    var arr= [];
    while(i<input.length){
       string = input.charAt(i);

       if(string == string.toUpperCase()){
           string = string.toLowerCase();
           arr += string;
        }else {
           string = string.toUpperCase(); 
           arr += string;
       }
       i++;
    }
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While this answer will work, it'd probably help to clean up some of the code (for example, the empty `if()` before `if(string == string.toUpperCase())` to make it more readable

Comment: it was written by mistake. I cleared it. Please like the solution if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the string and use the map function to swap the case of letters.
2. We'll get the array from #1.
3. Join the array using join function.

`

```
let str = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jump Over A Crazy Dog'
let swapedStrArray = str.split('').map(a => {
    return a === a.toUpperCase() ? a.toLowerCase() : a.toUpperCase()
})

//join the swapedStrArray
swapedStrArray.join('')
console.log('swapedStrArray', swapedStrArray.join(''))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

A new solution using map

```js
let swappingCases = "So, today we have REALLY good day";

let swapping = swappingCases.split("").map(function(ele){

  return ele === ele.toUpperCase()? ele.toLowerCase() : ele.toUpperCase();
  
}).join("");

console.log(swapping);
```

Answer (score -1):

As a side note in addition to what has already been said, your original code could work with just some minor modifications: convert the string to an array of 1-character substrings (using split), process this array and convert it back to a string when you're done (using join).

NB: the idea here is to highlight the difference between accessing a character in a string (which can't be modified) and processing an array of substrings (which can be modified). Performance-wise, Fabricator's solution is probably better.

```
var swapCase = function(str){
    var letters = str.split("");

    for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){
            letters[i] = letters[i].toUpperCase();
        }else {
            letters[i] = letters[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    str = letters.join("");
    console.log(str);
}

var text = 'So, today we have REALLY good day';

swapCase(text);
```