# Convert uppercase and lowercase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, lowercase

I want to make code that converts uppercase and lowercase in JavaScript.

For example, 'Hi, Stack Overflow.' → 'hI, sTACK oVERFLOW'

How can I do it?

Comment: did you try something ?

Answer (score 6):

You could run over each character, and then covert it to lowercase if it's in uppercase, to uppercase if it's in lowercase or take it as is if it's neither (if it's a comma, colon, etc):

```
str = 'Hi, Stack Overflow.';
res = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    c = str[i];
  if (c == c.toUpperCase()) {
    res += c.toLowerCase();
  } else if (c == c.toLowerCase()) {
    res += c.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    res += c;
  }
}
```

Comment: See also this answer for a little more advanced solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38703925/1743938

Comment: It's generally not considered mutating a string directly (by accessing it's index). It's usually preferred to convert it to an array (using .split() without any parameter), then iterate over the array and reassemble the string with .join(). Just as an idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this simple solution using `map()`

```js
var a = 'Hi, Stack Overflow!'

var ans = a.split('').map(function(c){
  return c === c.toUpperCase()
  ? c.toLowerCase()
  : c.toUpperCase()
}).join('')

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

A function which will do this for you (also [at CodePen](http://codepen.io/LewisYearsley/pen/RGEzXA?editors=1010)):

```
function reverseCase(input) {
    var output = []
    for(var char in input) {
        var character = input[char]
        if(character == character.toUpperCase())
            output.push(character.toLowerCase())
        else
            output.push(character.toUpperCase())
    }
    return output.join('')
}
```

Comment: The CodePen link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 'Hi, Stack Overflow.';

    alert(caseAlter(x));

    function caseAlter(txt){
        var output = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
            if(txt[i] == txt[i].toUpperCase()){
                output += txt[i].toLowerCase();
            }else{
                output += txt[i].toUpperCase();
            }           
        }

        return output;
    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var hi = 'Hi, Stack Overflow.';

var hI = hi.split("");
for(var i=0; i<hI.length; i++) {
    if(hI[i] == hI[i].toLowerCase())

        hI[i] = hI[i].toUpperCase();

    else if(hI[i] == hI[i].toUpperCase())
        hI[i] = hI[i].toLowerCase();
}

hI = hI.join("");
alert(hI);
//'hI, sTACK oVERFLOW'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = 'Hi, Stack Overflow.'
var arr = input.split(' ');

alert(arr);
var output = arr.map(function(elem){

  return (elem[0].toLowerCase() + elem.substring(1,elem.length).toUpperCase());

});

alert(output.join());
```