# Javascript - convert value of object to uppercase

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an object in my Angular.io or IONIC

```
{name:"food panda", city:"selangor", phone:"0123456789"}
```

and use the following code but it's not working:

```
this.restaurant.name.toUpperCase();
```

I need to convert `food panda` to `FOOD PANDA`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `toUpperCase()` doesn't mutate the original. You need to save it back: `this.restaurant.name = this.restaurant.name.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap Case on javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471618/swap-case-on-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> toUpperCase returns a new String, it doesn't modify the original

```js
var restaurant = { name: "food panda", city: "selangor", phone: "0123456789" };

restaurant.name.toUpperCase();

console.log(restaurant.name);           // output: food panda

var restaurantName = restaurant.name.toUpperCase();

console.log(restaurantName);            // output: FOOD PANDA
```

Answer (score 2):

`toUpperCase()` creates a copy of the string and changes that one to uppercase.  If you want the original string to be changed, you will need to reassign the string:

`this.restaurant.name = this.restaurant.name.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the resulting value, `toUpperCase()` does not modify anything.

```
var d = {name:"food panda", city:"selangor", phone:"0123456789"};
var name = d.name.toUpperCase();
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk0p4gwc/4/)

Comment: This is not OK!

Comment: You probably don't want to overwrite the whole object.

Comment: Well no, probably not, but for the purpose of showing OP that the value needs to be  stored it seemed adequate. You are correct though, I've edited my answer to reflect this.