# convert capital letters into small and small letters into capital

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "HellO WoRld"
var myArr = str.split(" ");
for(i=0;i<myArr.length;i++)
{
    myArr2 =myArr[i].split("");
    // console.log(myArr2);
        for(j=0;j<myArr2.length;j++)
        {
         if(myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) >= 65 && myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) <= 90  )
         {
            document.write(myArr2[j].toLowerCase());
         }
         else  if(myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) >= 97 && myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) <= 122  )
         {
            document.write(myArr2[j].toUpperCase());
         }
    }
}
```

So guys i have  been trying to change the letters in my word from caps to small and vice versa using charCodeAt(), can u guys tell me whats wrong in my code or suggest an alternative code but using charCodeAt() only.
Here from my code, input is HellO WoRld and output should be hELLo wOrLD but i am getting output as hw.

Comment: try `str.split("")` split without space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap Case on javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471618/swap-case-on-javascript)

Comment: Thanks that was so simple but even though i am getting an output its not 100% perfect since my input is "HellO WoRld" but the output what i am getting is "hELLowOrLD"  as you can notive no space between hello and world any suggestions for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "HellO WoRld"
var myArr = str.split("");
for(i=0;i<myArr.length;i++)
{
    myArr2 =myArr[i].split("");
    // console.log(myArr2);
        for(j=0;j<myArr2.length;j++)
        {
         if(myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) >= 65 && myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) <= 90  )
         {
            console.log(myArr2[j].toLowerCase());
         }
         else  if(myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) >= 97 && myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j) <= 122  )
         {
            console.log(myArr2[j].toUpperCase());
         }
    }
}
```

Your problem is with `str.split(" ")`, remove the extra space and split without space should be working fine `var myArr = str.split("")` @ line2

Comment: Thanks that was so simple but even though i am getting an output its not 100% perfect since my input is "HellO WoRld" but the output what i am getting is "hELLowOrLD" as you can notive no space between hello and world any suggestions for that

Comment: @JustaGamer: What you mean? I've pointed out the issue and you can check by simply clicking "Run code snippet" to see the result

Comment: Why just do someone's homework instead of helping them figure it out for themselves?

Comment: @DaveNewton: At least to me, SO is a place to seek help when you facing a difficulty, be it in your work or homework, doesn't matter. But most importantly you've tried and have attempt. The code that OP posted sure does looks like an attempted solution to me, just couldn't get his objective

Comment: So a simple explanation of where the OP went wrong, with links to and a summary of the relevant documents should be sufficient then-which also provides the means to the op to figure out how to figure things out. YMMV, but I'd rather teach beginners how to learn than hand them code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the `charCodeAt` function.  This function already takes the character position as an input, but you are specifying that information twice, e.g.

```
myArr2[j].charCodeAt(j)
```

Instead, try this version:

```js
var str = "HellO WoRld"
var myArr = str.split(" ");
var out = "";

for (i=0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var word = myArr[i];
    var output = "";
    console.log(word);
    for (j=0; j < word.length; j++) {
        if (word.charCodeAt(j) >= 65 && word.charCodeAt(j) <= 90) {
            output += String.fromCharCode(word.charCodeAt(j) + 32);
        }
        else if (word.charCodeAt(j) >= 97 && word.charCodeAt(j) <= 122) {
            output += String.fromCharCode(word.charCodeAt(j) - 32);
        }
    }
    if (out !== "") {
        out += " ";
    }
    out += output;
    console.log(output);
}

console.log("final output: " + out);
```

If you need to write this output to the DOM, I would recommend building the string first in your JavaScript code, and then doing a single DOM update, rather than going one character at a time.

Comment: @JustaGamer I have updated to give you an option for building the exact final output you want, with spaces.

Comment: Thank goodness someone was here to do his homework for him. I'd have assumed you'd direct the OP to figuring it out on their own instead of just handing them the answer :(

Comment: @DaveNewton Believe it or not, the possibiity that this is a homework dump never entered into my mind while I was answering.  But, now that you mention it, yeah, this probably was homework.

Comment: @DaveNewton well, its not at all homework ,i have been learning javascript from youtube and other online courses so had to ask to figure out what was wrong ,it was either trying myself the same prg for hours together or just figure out and move on to next

Comment: @JustaGamer How's that different from homework? In any case, that doesn't my point.