# How do you capitalize a whole word in javascript?

Tags: capitalization

can someone tell me how to capitalize my whole name from Jason Sims to JASON SIMS please!

````
    ['Name:', 'Jason Sims'],
    ['Career: Welder'],
    ['Description: In transition to becoming a developer!'],
];```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before asking a question research to see if it is similar to other answered questions. Do the answers to this question answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471618/swap-case-on-javascript ? If not edit your question so that it is specific about what is being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way

```js
var name = "Whatever";
console.log(name.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` for it:

```js
const data = [
  ['Name:', 'Jason Sims'],
  ['Career: Welder'],
  ['Description: In transition to becoming a developer!'],
];

const altData = data.map(pair => {
  return pair[0] === 'Name:' ? [pair[0], pair[1].toUpperCase()] : pair;
});

console.log(altData)
```