# how to interchange uppercase and lowercase letters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My program must change the case of my word on **UpperCase** or **LowerCase**.

**Example:**

word: "cAPS"

solution: "Caps"

All good, but.

My program works well with one word.

The program checks case of my word by two first symbols(Uppercase or Lower case) But when deal going to sentence I have a problem.

I do not understand, how method I must use. Maybe need to use an array or cycle to doing this?

**My problem:**

word: "wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK?"

Code of my program:

```js
let newWord = 'cAPS'
word = newWord

if (word.length > 1) {
  var lengthWord = word.length
  if (word.substring(1) == word.toUpperCase().substring(1)) {
    newWord = word.toUpperCase(0, 1).substring(0, 1) +
      word.toLowerCase().substring(1)
    console.log(newWord)
  } else if (word.substring(0) == word.toUpperCase().substring(0)) {
    newWord = word.toLowerCase().substring(0)
    console.log(newWord)
  } else if (word.substring(0, 1) == word.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1)) {
    newWord = word
    console.log(newWord)
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like? 
from:  "wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK?") to what?

Comment: Result: Why do We need Caps Lock?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the question".

Comment: Seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471618/swap-case-on-javascript

Comment: `words.style.textTransform = capitalize;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
let s = "wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK?" ;

let finalS = s.split(' ').reduce((result,word)=>{
   let cleanWord = [...word].map((char,index)=>index===0 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase() ).join('');
   return `${result} ${cleanWord}`
},'');

console.log(finalS);
```

Comment: Yes, that it !!!!

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Capitalize first letter of every word

```js
word = newWord.split(' ').map(innerWord => `${innerWord[0].toUpperCase()}${innerWord.split('').slice(1).join('')}`);
```

### Solution 2: Capitalize only the first letter of a set of words

```js
word = `${newWord[0].toUpperCase()}${newWord.split('').slice(1).join('')}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple and easy way convert string  UpperCase of each word .

```js
var mystring = "wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK"
var mystring_split = mystring.split(" ")
complete = []

mystring_split.forEach(myFunction);
 function myFunction(item, index) {
   word= item
  if (word.length > 1)
{
var lengthWord = word.length
if (word.substring(1) == word.toUpperCase().substring(1)) {
   newWord = word.toUpperCase(0, 1).substring(0, 1) + 
   word.toLowerCase().substring(1)
   complete.push(newWord)
}
return complete

}
}

console.log( complete.join(" "))
```